# AngularJS performance issue ng-model vs ng-class etc

Tags: angularjs

I have a list with ng-repeat in angular and a button which toggle checked property in all items (1.4):

```
<button ng-click="selectAll()">select all</button>
```

example 1:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"> {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

example 2:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': item.checked}"></span> {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

example 3:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-show="item.checked"></span> {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

example 4:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>{{ item.checked }}</span> {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

Performance of example 1 and 4 is OK. But example 2 and 3 has almost 1 sec. lag. There about 200 items in the array.

Why the performance is so different? I would like to have custom "checkboxes" with glyphicon - so I would like to have example 2 work but the performance is bad

Comment: How are you tracking the performance?  My guess is that you're tapping into the CSS which adds some overhead to the render time.  One thing you might do to improve your performance is use the `track by <expression>` syntax.  This allows the DOM to be recycled in some cases. Conversely excluding a `track by` expression means new DOM elements are created each time the `items` array is updated (not sure if that applies only to *pushed* items or the whole list gets dumped and rerendered).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for example 2:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.checked">
    <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': item.checked}"></span>
    {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

For example 3, try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.checked">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-if="item.checked"></span> {{ item.name }} 
</li>
```

Comment: track by have to be unique, imo. item.checked does not seems like unique. better use $index.